# Cucumber tests - break

Tags: testing, cucumber, outline, scenarios

I have a scenario outline with around 4 examples

```
Scenario Outline: Select Customer
    Given I am in "home" page
    When I click on <person>
    Then I should see results
    Examples: 
      | person | 
      | john   |
      | john   | 
      | john   |        
      | john   |
```

if there is error in selecting first example then it must skips other examples and end the file

Comment: Are you saying that if the first example fails, it should not execute any of the other examples in the current scenario, and it should not execute any other scenarios in the same feature file?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario Outlines are just a mechanism for writing several individual scenarios in a more compact form.

What you actually have here is

```
Scenario:
Given I am in "home" page
When I click on John
Then I should see results

Scenario:
Given I am in "home" page
When I click on Fred
Then I should see results

...
```

and what you are asking is that the test suite should stop running if any scenario fails.

Having a suite of tests fail as soon as one test fails really doesn't make sense for a testing tool.